# eBay API GetFeedback call returns 'Input data for tag <GetFeedback> is invalid or missing' error

Tags: ebay-api, review

I try to get all feedback (CommentType [positive,neutral,negative], user who left, date, message) for the particular user in xml format. For this I use http request:

```
https://api.ebay.com/wsapi?callname=GetFeedback&UserID=pashtetgp1988&siteid=0&DetailLevel=ReturnAll&appid=eBayAPID-73f4-45f2-b9a3-c8f6388b38d8&version=511
```

However, xml output returns error

```
Input data for tag <GetFeedback> is invalid or missing. Please check API documentation.
```

Another request with the same appid works fine:

```
http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetUserProfile&version=537&siteid=0&appid=eBayAPID-73f4-45f2-b9a3-c8f6388b38d8&UserID=pashtetgp1988&IncludeSelector=Details,FeedbackHistory&responseencoding=XML
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*GetFeedback* is from of the [eBay Trading API Service](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/index.html) and you cannot make calls to this service using HTTP GET. The service only supports requests made by HTTP POST. Information required by *GetFeedback* is passed either through the HTTP headers or the body. The body of the request can be XML or SOAP. More information is available in the eBay [documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Concepts/MakingACall.html).

For future reference you **should never** expose your *appid* in code examples.